# Toggle HDR mode in macOS 12

Tags: macos

```
tell application "System Preferences"
set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.displays"
tell application "System Events"
    tell window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
        click checkbox "High Dynamic Range" of window "Displays" of application process "System Preferences" of application "System Events"
    end tell
end tell
```

I'm using macOS 12.
It's not working. Help me please.

[macos12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmKC8.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: See my answer at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387482/27373 and use the UI Browser app to figure out the name of the button you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you *@Zade*.
I solved it to use the UI Browser.

```
on run
  activate application "System Preferences"
  tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click button "Displays" of scroll area 1 of window "System Preferences"
        delay 2
        click checkbox "High Dynamic Range, Automatically adjust the display to show high dynamic range content." of group 1 of window "Displays"
    end tell
    delay 1
    quit application "System Preferences"
  end tell 
end run
```